# Hello, How do i get int value from multiple JComboBox and set the sum of this numbers in a JTextBox

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox

This is a sample of the code I am working on. I can get the numbers contained in the JComboBox but i have problem adding the sum of them to the JtextField

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;

public class Sample {

  private JFrame frame;

  public JTextField totalVal;

  public int valASet;

  public int valBSet;

  public int totalSum;

  /* Launch the application.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          Sample window = new Sample();
          window.frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Create the application.
   */
  public Sample() {
    initialize();
  }

  /**
   * Initialize the contents of the frame.
   */
  private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 425, 185);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
    Panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
    Panel.setBounds(121, 41, 211, 42);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Panel);
    Panel.setLayout(null);
```

Getting the value of JComboBox #1 to the first integer var

```
    JComboBox valA = new JComboBox();
    valA.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {
      public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {}
      public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        String valANum = (String) valA.getSelectedItem();
        valASet = Integer.parseInt(valANum);

      }
      public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {}
    });
```

Getting the value of JComboBox #2 to the second integer var

```
    JComboBox valB = new JComboBox();
    valB.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {
      public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {}
      public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        String valBNum = (String) valB.getSelectedItem();
        valBSet = Integer.parseInt(valBNum);

      }
      public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {}
    });
    valA.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {
      "0",
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4"
    }));
    valA.setBounds(77, 11, 57, 20);
    Panel.add(valA);
```

Although totalSum recognise the +10 int value it does not add the other two variables.

```
    totalVal = new JTextField();
    totalVal.setEditable(false);
    totalVal.setBounds(10, 11, 57, 20);
    Panel.add(totalVal);
    totalSum = valASet + valBSet + 10;
    String totalString = Integer.toString(totalSum);
    totalVal.setText(totalString);
    totalVal.setColumns(10);


    valB.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {
      "0",
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4"
    }));
    valB.setBounds(144, 11, 57, 20);
    Panel.add(valB);
  }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your [mcve] code about the best we can do is to suggest that you check out the Swing tutorials.  Else we have no idea what you could be doing wrong.  You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but please do read or re-read the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link provided since your tiny code snippet does not compile nor run for us, nor does it tell us what you're doing wrong. We don't want you to post your entire program, but just *enough* so that the code compiles, runs, and shows us the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Don't use a `PopupMenuListener` but rather an `ActionListener`, and sum the values ***within*** the listener

Comment: See edits to answer please

Answer (score 1):

No where in your current code post do you do any summation of values, and this needs to be done within an event listener -- it needs to occur when the user changes the state of one of the GUI's JComboBoxes.

You need to add an ActionListener to each JComboBox, and the *same* listener will work. Within the listener, you simply iterate through the JComboBoxes, extracting the values they hold, use that to update a sum variable and then set the JTextField. Best to put the JComboBoxes into an ArrayList to make this iteration much more easily performed. For example, something like this MCVE

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Sample2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int COMBO_COUNT = 6;
    private static final Integer[] ITEMS = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

    // ArrayList that holds all JComboBoxes
    private List<JComboBox<Integer>> combos = new ArrayList<>();
    private JTextField resultField = new JTextField(10);

    public Sample2() {
        resultField.setFocusable(false); // don't allow editing of this

        // single ActionListener added to all JComboBoxes
        ActionListener comboListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int sum = 0;
                // iterate through the list, adding the values
                for (JComboBox<Integer> jComboBox : combos) {
                    Integer selection = (Integer) jComboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    sum += selection == null ? 0 : selection;
                }
                resultField.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            }
        };
        add(resultField);

        for (int i = 0; i < COMBO_COUNT; i++) {
            JComboBox<Integer> combo = new JComboBox<>(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(ITEMS));
            // add the ActionListener to the combo box
            combo.addActionListener(comboListener);
            // add the combo box to the list
            combos.add(combo);
            // add it to the GUI
            add(combo);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Sample2 mainPanel = new Sample2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Also, a side issue: You should avoid use of null layout and use of `setBounds(...)` for component placement as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain.

So why go through this bother of layout managers? Say I wanted to "prettify" my GUI and make it look a little like yours, an inner border around the JTextField and the JComboBoxes, I can do this by nesting JPanels, using layouts (see comments) like so:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Sample2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int COMBO_COUNT = 6;
    private static final Integer[] ITEMS = { 
            -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, 
            -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 
            0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
            6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    private static final int GAP1 = 15;
    private static final int GAP2 = 30;
    private static final int TXTFLD_COLS = 5;

    // ArrayList that holds all JComboBoxes
    private List<JComboBox<Integer>> combos = new ArrayList<>();
    private JTextField resultField = new JTextField("0", TXTFLD_COLS);

    public Sample2() {
        // inner JPanel to hold the JComboBoxes and text field
        // give it a grid layout, 1 row, variable # cols
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, GAP1/2, 0));
        // give it a line border with some padding 
        Border outerBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE);
        Border innerBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP1, GAP1, GAP1, GAP1);
        Border combinedBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outerBorder, innerBorder);

        innerPanel.setBorder(combinedBorder);
        resultField.setFocusable(false); // don't allow editing of this

        // single ActionListener added to all JComboBoxes
        ActionListener comboListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int sum = 0;
                // iterate through the list, adding the values
                for (JComboBox<Integer> jComboBox : combos) {
                    Integer selection = (Integer) jComboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    sum += selection == null ? 0 : selection;
                }
                resultField.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            }
        };
        innerPanel.add(resultField);

        for (int i = 0; i < COMBO_COUNT; i++) {
            JComboBox<Integer> combo = new JComboBox<>(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(ITEMS));
            combo.setSelectedItem(0);
            // add the ActionListener to the combo box
            combo.addActionListener(comboListener);
            // add the combo box to the list
            combos.add(combo);
            // add it to the GUI
            innerPanel.add(combo);
        }

        // GridBagLayout is one way to allow us to add 
        // the inner JPanel in the very center
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP2, GAP2, GAP2, GAP2));
        add(innerPanel);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Sample2 mainPanel = new Sample2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Now say I wanted to change the number of JComboBoxes from 6 to 10. If I were setting bounds, I'd have to muck with absolute positions and sizes of a bunch of components, making a bunch of needless extra work with increased risk of errors/bugs. But with my code, I would need to change but a *single line*, changing this:

```
private static final int COMBO_COUNT = 6;
```

which creates:

[image: small GUI]

to this:

```
private static final int COMBO_COUNT = 10;
```

which creates this:

[image]

And the layout managers would do all the scutwork for me.